# Decorators not allowed in IIFE Self-Executing Anonymous Class

Tags: typescript

Decorators are not allowed in self-executing classes/functions, anyone knows if there is any reason behind it?

```
//Getting compiler error 'decorators are not valid here'
void new (class {
  ...
  @autobind
  private submitHandler(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.log(this.titleInputElement.value);
  }
  ...
})();
```

Comment: Added ^^

@CertainPerformance